# C word counter and punctuation counter

Tags: c

I was able to program with such structure and also acknowledge that I have to use `ispunct()` and `isspace()` in order to count the  number of punctuation and words. But I am not sure how to program with such functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int WordCount(char *input, int size)
{
    //programming here//
}

int PunctuationCount(char *input, int size)
{
    //programming here//
}

int main(void)
{
    char test1[] = "Hello, World!";
    char test2[] = "She sell sea shell on a sea shore. The shells she sells are sea-shells. I'm sure? For if she sells sea-shells on the sea-shore, then I'm sure she sells sea-shore shells!";
    char test3[] = "VISION 2020 embodies every SKKU student's dream, will, and destiny to make SKKU a global leading university. To successfully establish VISION 2020, SKKU will pursue 'The 5 Core Strategies' and '5 Divisional Strategies'. The Strategic Tasks for 5 Major Areas are the general tasks that influence SKKU's competitiveness.";

    printf("test1 has %d punctuations, %d words.\n", PunctuationCount(test1,sizeof(test1)/sizeof(char)), WordCount(test1,sizeof(test2)/sizeof(char)));
    printf("test2 has %d punctuations, %d words.\n", PunctuationCount(test2,sizeof(test2)/sizeof(char)), WordCount(test2,sizeof(test2)/sizeof(char)));
    printf("test3 has %d punctuations, %d words.\n", PunctuationCount(test3,sizeof(test3)/sizeof(char)), WordCount(test3,sizeof(test2)/sizeof(char)));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `C++`?

Comment: What specifically are you "not sure" about? P.S. Parameters to two out of the three calls to `WordCount()` are obviously wrong.

Comment: But the requirement of this project is to have 2 separate functions for punctuation and word counter. What other method do you suggest?

Comment: You misunderstood the comment. You have `sizeof(test2)` in all the `WordCount` calls which is clearly wrong.

Comment: As for your question overall - it is too broad. We can help you with specific problems but not such broad questions. You need to make an attempt, show the attempted code and ask a specific question about the code.

Comment: The API seems incorrect: the pointer should have type `const char *` and why pass the number of characters instead of relying on the null terminator. A simpler prototype would be `size_t PunctuationCount(const char *input);`. The problem statement is too vague: what is the definition of a *word* and what is the set of *punctuation* characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int WordCount(char input[], int size)
{
    int count =0;
    int i = 0;
    while (input[i])
    {
        if(isspace(input[i])!=0) count++;
        i++;
    }
    return count+1;
}
int PunctuationCount(char input[], int size)
{
    int count =0;
    int i = 0;
    while (input[i])
    {
        if(ispunct(input[i])!=0) count++;
        i++;        
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: The loops test for the null terminator instead of the number of characters specified as `size`. Furthermore, the `WordCount` should probably count the number of words, instead of the number of spaces. For example: `WordCount("Hello  World", 5)` should return `2`, not `3` and `WordCount("", 0)` should return `0`, not `1`.

Comment: Hi @chqrlie, doesn't size (redundantly I might add,) just tell the routine the number of characters in the string? As such, implementations can just ignore it (if not complain about it.)

Comment: Indeed the size argument is redundant if it is meant to be the length of the string, and as you have noticed, the OP makes multiple mistakes in the posted code: the value passed for `WordCount` uses the wrong string and includes the null terminator. In your answer, you should either remove the argument and rely on the null terminator or use the length and make no assumption about the string length.

Answer (score 0):

Please note, this algo does not handle hyphenated words or contractions. (That's your job!)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int WordCount(char *input, int size)
{
    int inword=0;
    int count=0;
    for (;*input; input++)
        if (isalpha((int) *input))
        {   // does not handle hyphenated words or contractions
            inword=1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (inword)
            {
                inword=0;
                count++;
            }
        }

    return count;
}

int PunctuationCount(char *input, int size)
{
    int count=0;
    for (;*input; input++)
        if (ispunct((int) *input))
        {   // does not handle hyphenated words or contractions
            count++;
        }

    return count;
}

int main(void)
{
    char test1[] = "Hello, World!";
    char test2[] = "She sell sea shell on a sea shore. The shells she sells are sea-shells. I'm sure? For if she sells sea-shells on the sea-shore, then I'm sure she sells sea-shore shells!";
    char test3[] = "VISION 2020 embodies every SKKU student's dream, will, and destiny to make SKKU a global leading university. To successfully establish VISION 2020, SKKU will pursue 'The 5 Core Strategies' and '5 Divisional Strategies'. The Strategic Tasks for 5 Major Areas are the general tasks that influence SKKU's competitiveness.";

    printf("test1 has %d punctuations, %d words.\n", PunctuationCount(test1,sizeof(test1)/sizeof(char)), WordCount(test1,sizeof(test2)/sizeof(char)));
    printf("test2 has %d punctuations, %d words.\n", PunctuationCount(test2,sizeof(test2)/sizeof(char)), WordCount(test2,sizeof(test2)/sizeof(char)));
    printf("test3 has %d punctuations, %d words.\n", PunctuationCount(test3,sizeof(test3)/sizeof(char)), WordCount(test3,sizeof(test2)/sizeof(char)));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The loops test for the null terminator instead of the number of characters specified as `size`.  Instead of `isalpha((int) *input)` you should cast `char` values as `unsigned char` to avoid undefined behavior on negative `char` values: `isalpha((unsigned char)*input)`. Also digits should probably be handled as word characters: `WordCount("99 birds on a wire", 18)` should return `5`.